# how to more efficiently manage network protocol in java

Tags: java, networking

I'm developing a network based program in java, and I designed my own network protocol. Here is what I usually did to handle incoming message:

```
socket = ss.accept();
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String msg = null;
while(true)
if((msg=in.readLine())!=null){
//handle msg with designed protocol here
    }
```

It is ok to do this when the protocol is simple enough, but when it becomes complex, it is overwhelming to put everything here,it also makes my code harder to understand. My question is that, is there any way to store the protocol code in another place? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your loop is wrong anyway. If 'readLine()' returns null you must close and break out of the loop. Get rid of the 'while(true)' and change the 'if' to 'while'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, why not? Just make another class and make a method that does the handling. Send the `msg` to it and and do the handling there. Or make another method in the same class with:

`public (static) void handle(String msg) { //Handle message }`